# Generate inserts using SQLcl inside a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table in oracle, with a list of tickets, each ticket is from a client.

I need to generate a list of inserts of this tickets for each client.

I think in create something like this, iterate a list of clients from other table and export inserts using set format, but it don't work.

This is my code.

```
set sqlformat insert
spool "/test/inserts_clients.sql";


BEGIN
FOR item IN
    (SELECT cli_id from clients)
LOOP


select tickets.*
    from tickets
    where tickets.cli_id = item.cli_id

END LOOP;
END;


spool off;
quit;
```

Comment: that's not going to work.  get rid of the pl/sql and just do a select and join with the client tables

Comment: Looping in an RDBMS is always a last resort and the rest of the time is a terrible idea. Why not just `SELECT tickets.* FROM tickets t INNER JOIN clients c on t.cli_id = c.cli_id`. Then if this data needs to be split for each `cli_id`, do it in whatever application is consuming this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use PL/SQL and loops (as context-switching between PL/SQL and SQL is slow and need an `INTO` clause with a `SELECT` statement in the PL/SQL scope); instead just use SQL and an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
select t.*
from   tickets t
       INNER JOIN clients c
       ON (t.cli_id = c.cli_id)
ORDER BY c.cli_id;
```